# Android Google Login

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

I am trying to add google login to my app, but it is not so easy for me. I figured out, that problem is somewhere in wersions, but i cannot handle it. Can you please help me ?
My app level build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.goodrequest.quotes"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

LOG:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.goodrequest.quotes, PID: 7474
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6008)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5590)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5529)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1576)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.goodrequest.quotes-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.goodrequest.quotes-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6008) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5529) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1576) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Why you have deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626754/firebase-add-child-success-listener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing Firebase Auth gradle dependency in your build.gradle file.
Add below dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

[How to implement Google Sign In?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

Comment: problem was in  bad version of  firebase
changed :
**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0**
to:
**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'**

Comment: yeah.. we should try to use latest version in gradle dependency otherwise it might give us conflicts error.